# Xcode 13.3 started giving Error: missingKey("url") for SPM based app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode13

My app using SPM package dependencies used to throw a different error on Xcode 13.2.1. When I switched to use Xcode 13.3, I suddenly started getting

```
Error: missingKey("url")
```

Has something changed with `Package.swift`  syntax in Xcode 13.3 that would give this error? The app builds with a script from command line.

Comment: You should probably specify swift-tools-version.

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes on **SPM** with Xcode 13.3, for example one of my packages had a dependency to another package, and I had to change how to specify that dependency.

#### From (not working anymore on Xcode 13.3)

```swift
.package(name: "PackageName", url: "https://github.com/orgname/package.git", .branch("main"))
```

#### To (working on Xcode 13.3)

```swift
.package(url: "https://github.com/orgname/package.git", branch: "main")
```

---

Maybe you have a similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was with SPM version specified in `Package.swift`

I was using `// swift-tools-version:5.3`. Xcode 13.3 needs this to be `// swift-tools-version:5.6`.